# Angular view to Ionic view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

What am I doing wrong? I've followed countless tutorials on `Youtube`/`Google` and yet it doesn't seem to be working.

I want to load games and when you click on one of them, it should give a `detail view`. This all worked fine in `Angular` only, but I wanted to try in Ionic for the `animation`.

**Note: Following code is to display the list of games.**

### Index.html

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <script id="list.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </script>
  </body>
```

### Controller

```
var ctrl = angular.module('Controllers', []);

ctrl.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'games', function($scope, $http, $location, games){

  $scope.games = [];

  $scope.games = games.all();

}]);
```

You can assume I get data in code above.

### App config

```
app.config(['$stateProvider',function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('list', {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
      controller: 'MainController'
    })
}])
```

### List.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Games">
  <ion-refresher pulling-text="Refresh..." on-refresh="refresh()"></ion-refresher>

  <ion-content>
    <div class="game" ng-repeat="game in games.results" ng-click="checkDetail(game, $index)">
      <!--<img ng-src="{{ game.image.screen_url }}" alt="{{ game.aliases }}" />-->
      <h3>{{ game.name }}</h3>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

### Codepen

Here's a `codepen` I based it on
http://codepen.io/darrenahunter/pen/oDKid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare a ui-view to inject template from state.
Edit your index.html like that :

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ui-view>
    </div>
</body>
```

### or

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <ion-nav-view name="content"></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

and edit your state like that

```
.state('statename', {
     url: "/",
     views: {
         'content': {
             templateUrl: 'yourTemplate.html',
             controller: "yourCtrl"
         }
     }
}
```

that way you force to inject your view in that ion-nav-view.

The same way you can create

```
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
```

Comment: I've added the `ui-view`but nothing appears. It did throw an error (that I fixed) on the `list.html` file so I think it's getting closer.

Comment: Wait, it does work. I assumed I had data in my array but I hadn't  lol.. Thanks! The `ui-view`solved it